# PHP: Match text respectively with querystring

Tags: php, jquery, match, echo, href

I have the following line:

```
<a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a>
```

And I use jquery code to echo (match) whatever between the `> <` brackets and makes the link as follows:

```
<a href="page.php?q=Mt 5: 2">Mt 5: 2</a>
```

Now I need the link to be as follows:

```
<a href="page.php?book=Mt&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>
```

The code I am currently using to match all is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[href='page.php']").each(function(index, element){
   href = $(element).attr('href');
   $(element).attr('href', href + "?q=" + $(element).text());
});
});
```

So I need to divide whatever between the `> <` to three sections respectively:

1. adds Mt to ?book= → ?book=Mt
2. adds 5 to &chapter= → &chapter=5
3. adds 2 to &vmin= → &vmin=2

Comment: This format (`Mt 5: 2`) of text is fixed for all `<a>` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. no it changes, like verses.. example: <a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a> - <a href="page.php">Mt 7: 4</a> - <a href="page.php">Mk 12: 27</a> - <a href="page.php">Rv 15: 12</a> etc.

Comment: The current code matches all the text between > < and makes the link like that: <a href="page.php?q=Mt 5: 2">Mt 5: 2</a>  -  what I need is to edit the code to make the link like that: <a href="page.php?book=Mt&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>

Comment: Yes, thats what I was asking, the format remains the same but the value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split text of each link and use all three values separately to make your desired `href` like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href='page.php']").each(function(index, element){
    href = $(element).attr('href'); // get the href
    text = $(element).text().split(' '); // get the text and split it with space
    $(element).attr('href', href + "?book=" +$.trim(text[0])+"&chapter="+$.trim(text[1].slice(0,-1))+"&vmin="+$.trim(text[2])); //create desired href and replace it with older-one
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a><br>
<a href="page.php">Mt 7: 2</a><br>
<a href="page.php">Mt 10: 2</a><br>
```

Note:-

`trim()` used to remove extra spaces if the value have any(leading/trailing spaces).

`slice()` used to remove `:` from the second value.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @IcedAnt  glad to hear that :):)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks a lot, here is the link of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558775/php-replace-matched-text-with-querystring