# PHP: Replace Matched text with querystring

Tags: php, jquery, match, href

I have a list of abbreviations like verses:

```
Mt=80
Lu=81
Rv=92
Nd=95
etc.
```

And I am currently jquery to convert these links:

```
<a href="page.php?q=Mt 5: 2">Mt 5: 2</a>
<a href="page.php?q=Mt 5: 2">Nd 14: 25</a>
```

and makes them as follows:

```
<a href="page.php?book=Mt&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>
<a href="page.php?book=Nd&chapter=15&vmin=25">Nd 14: 25</a>
```

The script being used to that is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href='page.php']").each(function(index, element){
    href = $(element).attr('href'); // get the href
    text = $(element).text().split(' '); // get the text and split it with space
    $(element).attr('href', href + "?book=" +$.trim(text[0])+"&chapter="+$.trim(text[1].slice(0,-1))+"&vmin="+$.trim(text[2])); //create desired href and replace it with older-one
  });
});
```

What I need is to translate the text between `> <` to the appropriate number (Mt=80, Lu=81, Rv=92, Nd=95.. etc.), so the converted links becomes like:

```
<a href="page.php?book=80&chapter=5&vmin=2">Mt 5: 2</a>
<a href="page.php?book=95&chapter=15&vmin=25">Nd 14: 25</a>
```

Comment: Why `14: 25` is converted to `&chapter=15&vmin=25`? (Why `14:` becomes `chapter=15`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. just respectively.. trim() used to remove extra spaces if the value have any(leading/trailing spaces) and slice() used to remove : from the second value. - so the first is the book, second is chapter and third is vmin

Comment: @Mike  HE IS TALKING ABOUT `<a href="page.php?book=95&chapter=15&vmin=25">Nd 14: 25</a>`. Here `chapter=15` need to be `chapter=14`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a jQuery array with your pre-defined values and you have to use first value of link text as an array index to get corresponding value.

Check the below snippet:-

```js
var myarray = {'Mt':80, 'Lu':81, 'Rv':92, 'Nd':95};// you can add more values
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href='page.php']").each(function(index, element){
    href = $(element).attr('href'); // get the href
    text = $(element).text().split(' '); // get the text and split it with space
    $(element).attr('href', href + "?book=" +$.trim(myarray[text[0]])+"&chapter="+$.trim(text[1].slice(0,-1))+"&vmin="+$.trim(text[2])); //create desired href and replace it with older-one
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a><br>
<a href="page.php">Nd 14: 25</a>
```

Note:-

`myarray[text[0]] == myarray['Mt'] ==80; //.... so on for other values as well`

Comment: Works great, thanks..  However when I try to add Arabic in the array it doesn't work..  like {'كم':80}.. any suggestions?  Does it need some kind of encoding or something?

Comment: You are doing  error there. it need to be something like `{'Mt':'that arabic word'}`

Comment: I mean instead of <a href="page.php">Mt 5: 2</a> it is <a href="page.php">كم 5: 2</a>

Comment: you have to adjust code accordingly. Try something at your end too. If not worked, then go for new-one. Asking questions in comment is not a good idea. Please try to adjust code first.

Comment: @Mike  glad to help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558775/php-replace-matched-text-with-querystring